# Dynamic programming and Difference equations applications

Tags: dynamic-programming, bellman-equations, difference-equations

I'm asked by my teacher to prepare a presentation with economic applications of Dynamic Programing (Bellman Equation) and Difference equations. I'm not sure what this things are used for in economics so if someone could give me some topics I would be glad.

Sorry for my use of the language. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: In short - dynamic programming (DP) is a form of dynamic optimisation in which a very large complicated problem is broken into smaller sub-problems (which at least conceptually have a solution). Typically, DP is used in planning - or any other type of optimisation problem. This is a very good non-technical summary.https://faculty.arts.ubc.ca/fhoffmann/econ560/Review_Dynamic_Programming.pdf

Comment: I will leave others to highlight practical applications of difference equations, for which there are many.

Comment: Hi: If you google for "Chapter 7 Discrete-Time Discrete Space Dynamic Models", a nice chapter comes up with many decent looking (at a glance)  examples. I would send the link but, for some reason, it won't let me.